# issue with subprocess.popen

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess.popen to open an executable and pass an argument.  Currently, all it does is open the executable.  My code is below and I am running the code in Python 2.7 on a Windows machine.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(
    [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\PSSBIN\pssecmd33.exe",
     'exec contingency-33-32.irf'])
```

Comment: "all it does" as in, the argument doesn't seem to get used?

Comment: Have you tried making `'exec'` and `'contingency-33-32.irf'` separate items in the list? `popen` might be treating the whole `'exec contingency-33-32.irf'` as a single argument, where it's supposed to be two

Comment: I'm sorry, to clarify, it calls the program with the pssecmd33.exe command but does not perform the 'exec' command.  I tried braking up the 'exec' and 'contingency-33-32.irf' parts and the code produced the same result, which is the exe initialization followed by a prompt for input.  Thanks!